Will these two SAW filters for GPS L1 work the same?
I am trying my hand at making a GPS module with the Ublox NEO M9N Datasheet. The schematic I am referring to has this SAW filter F6QA1G582H2JM-J

In the datasheet the input and output terminals are marked. But this component is unavailable with my preferred PCB assembler.

They have suggested SAFFB1G56KB0F0AR1X instead. However it's datasheet does not make any mention about the input and output terminals, and instead call two unbalanced ports on pins 1 and 4.

Is there any impedance matching circuitry needed for the replacement filter or will it work mostly same ?
This is my version of the schematic. The traces have been made 50 Ohms according to the PCB stack up.


Pin 1 and 4 are 50 Ohm single ended (unbalanced) ports. Your choice which one you use as IN. The other one will then obviously be OUT. Pin 2,3,5 have to be tied to GND .
